# Is it possible to display colored text on a Canny Edge frame?

Tags: python, opencv, edge-detection, canny-operator

Please forgive me for the question, I am quite new to OpenCV. I am using canny edge detection on a people-counting program, and every time that a person walks into the frame an ID dot is placed in the center of the person. Before I applied code to generate the canny edges, I displayed the IDs as green, however, with the canny edges I can't see any color. Rather, the IDs are just outlines and nothing else. I would very much like to retain the color, as it would make it a lot easier to see with the black and white background.

Here is a picture of the frame that I have after Canny Edge has occurred

[image: Here is a picture of the frame that I have after Canny Edge has occurred]
In the bottom left, you can see some text that I would like to be colored, but that has been changed by the edges.

Is it possible to display colored text in conjunction with Canny Edge detection?

Comment: In c++, it can be done with copyto function. I dont know if the same function is available in python.

Comment: render the text after edge detection and converting the edge image to a 3 channel image.

Comment: Micka said it well. You can solve your issue in this way: perform edge detection, then convert the output (it's a single channel image) into a coloured image( gray2bgr should work), then render your text with your preferred color.

Comment: @MauroDorni if I am using OpenCV Version 4.1 I don't think the gray2bgr is possible, is there a different way to convert a 1 channel image to a 3 channel image?

Comment: Are you sure? https://docs.opencv.org/4.1.0/de/d25/imgproc_color_conversions.html, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY is here available

Comment: @MauroDorni Yes. I ran into an error where "'module' object has no attribute 'cv' " was returned. I found a way to convert to a 3 channel image by using np.stack instead and its close to working.

Comment: I tried using opencv 4.0.1 and it works, I guess it can be a different issue. Could you please post your code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tested using opencv 4.0.1 and it works as expected: you can convert edge output image to bgr image, then put all the colored elements youy need.
Here a small example how to do that:

```
    import cv2 as cv
    img = cv.imread(filename, cv.IMREAD_COLOR) 
    img_gray = cv.cvtColor(img, cv.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

    filt = cv.medianBlur(img_gray, 9)
    filt = cv.blur(filt, (3, 3))

    edges = cv.Canny(filt, 10, 50)

    edges_bgr = cv.cvtColor(edges, cv.COLOR_GRAY2BGR)
    w,h = edges_bgr.shape[:2]
    center = (int(h/2), int(w/2))
    radius = 100
    cv.circle(edges_bgr, center, radius, (255,128,0), 3)

    font = cv.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
    bottomLeftCornerOfText = center
    fontScale = 1
    lineType = 2

    cv.putText(edges_bgr,'Text with colors', 
                bottomLeftCornerOfText, 
                font, 
                fontScale,
                (0,128,255),
                lineType)

    cv.imshow("edges with colors", edges_bgr)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for the clarification. I would upvote, but I don't have enough reputation to do so.

Comment: Glad to hear that :) If it's ok you can just accept my answer, https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers